# React NextJs Add Link as componenet into a string

Tags: next.js

I need to build nextJs links programatically.
A simple example:

```
const link = <Link href={'/example'}>ipsum</Link>

const text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'

const replaced = text.replaceAll('ipsum', link);
```

But the result is:

```
Lorem [object Object] dolor sit amet
```

How can i replace a string with a link componenet without destroying the react component?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenating components in a string will result in displaying `[object Object]` because eventually that component is an object and will get coerced into a string to fit in.

What would work in react to achieve your goal is to use arrays instead.

```
  const link = <Link href={'/example'}>ipsum</Link>
  const text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
  const res = text.split(" ").reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (curr === "ipsum") {
      return [...acc, link];
    }
    return [...acc, ` ${curr} `];
  }, []);

  return <>{res}</>
```

The fragment would display the array of objects as you expect it to be.

Comment: This point me to the right direction. Thank you